# How to set Date limit to 6 months from current date Flutter?

Tags: flutter, date, dart, datepicker

I need to set the calendar limit to next 6 months from now. the code i tried to run is given below:

```
Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime.now(),
        lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().month + 6));
    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate)
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = picked;
      });
  }
```

When i try to run this code i get the given error:

```
Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/material/date_picker.dart': Failed assertion: line 226 pos 5: '!lastDate.isBefore(firstDate)': lastDate 0008-01-01 00:00:00.000 must be on or after firstDate 2022-02-09 00:00:00.000.
E/flutter ( 1931): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:46:39)
E/flutter ( 1931): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:36:5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A clean way to add something to a DateTime is:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.now();
DateTime myDateWithSixMonthsAdded = myDate.add(Duration(days: 180));
```

Add 180 days since **Duration** does not have a *months* parameter.

Comment: And thus it's approximately six months.  But Dates are hard, so this is likely as close as you get easily.

Answer (score 3):

Your `lastDate` input `DateTime(DateTime.now().month + 6))` is incorrect.

Since `DateTime.now().month + 6` will produce an `int`, `DateTime(DateTime.now().month + 6))` will be the year `DateTime.now().month + 6`.

Change that line to:

`lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month + 6, DateTime.now().day));`

Or use the `.add` function for `DateTime` class:

`DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 180));`